# How to change content-type but keep charset on Apache2?

Tags: apache, header, apache2, virtualhost, content-type

I have a Apache2 server on Ubuntu for proxy server. I want to change `content-type` of response to client to another but it will remove `charset` too.

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
Header set Content-Type "text/html" "expr=%{resp:Content-Type} =~ m|text/abcdefgh|"
```

With this setting, when it see the header which content-type is `text/abcdefgh` or `text/abcdefgh; charset=utf-8` or `text/abcdefgh; charset=shift_jis`, it will become `text/html` without `charset`

1. Is there any way to change part of `content-type` by `Header set` or `others`?
2. Where can I find the meaning of this pattern?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use `edit` instead of `set`?

```
Header edit Content-Type "text/abcdefgh" "text/html"
```

It should just replace `text/abcdefgh` with `text/html` but leave the charset as is